# Pymacs helper does not load

Tags: python, emacs, pymacs

I'm running emacs 22.1.1 on OS X version 10.8 (mountain lion) and I have started setting up pymacs, rope, ropemacs according to the instructions provided here:
http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/05/my-emacs-python-environment/

After reaching the stage before auto-complete-mode, I get the following error when starting emacs:

```
("emacs")
Loading encoded-kb...done

Loading advice...done
Pymacs loading ropemacs...

An error has occurred while loading `/Users/my_name/.emacs':

error: Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

After starting emacs with the --debug-init option I get

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds")
  signal(error ("Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds"))
  pymacs-report-error("Pymacs helper did not start within %d seconds" 30)
  pymacs-start-services()
  pymacs-serve-until-reply("eval" (pymacs-print-for-apply (quote "pymacs_load_helper")(quote ("ropemacs" "rop$
  pymacs-call("pymacs_load_helper" "ropemacs" "rope-")
  pymacs-load("ropemacs" "rope-")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/my_name/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 566
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/my_name/.emacs" "/Users/my_name/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "^H\205\276^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202A^@ \311=\2033^@\312\307\313\314#\203#^@\315\202A^@\312\30$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just some comment to boil down the matter: use function to call the init stuff after Emacs load.

Comment: I'm kind of inexperienced, so here it goes: How would I do this?

Comment: Why do you use Emacs 22? Can I persuade to install Emacs 24 and then install Pymacs according to [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22496541/596361)? Emacs 24 has a package manager, and `pymacs` is in http://marmalade-repo.org

Answer (score 0):

Did you use newest Pymacs? 
https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/tarball/v0.25

See the README how to install.

BTW Pymacs runs it's own mailing-list.

Answer (score 0):

I use this setup https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python. It has pymacs, rope, ropemacs, yasnippet, pyflakes integration. A complete python dev package for emacs and it just worked for me.
My setup - https://github.com/rags/.emacs.d (this includes emacs-for-python)