# Clear steps to install pymacs with emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, rope, pymacs

I want autocompletion and refactoring in emacs with python.

I gather that I need rope to do this.  To do this with emacs, I need ropemacs.  Ropmacs depends on pymacs.

Pymacs is hard to install...or at least the instructions are not clear to me.

Do I need to do two things?  Install pymacs and then install a file that tells emacs to talk to pymacs?  I've already installed rope and ropemacs super easily, with

`pip install rope ropemacs`

Here's what I did:

```
pip install -e "git+https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs.git#egg=Pymacs"
```

This installs ok on mac os x mountain lion according to PIP.

But I have a feeling that I am not done--or am I?

How do I test to see if pymacs and rope and ropemacs are all working?

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest way to install ropemacs is to use [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get): `M-x el-get-install ropemacs`.  It installs and build Pymacs, rope and ropemacs.  I know that it works on Linux.  See the el-get document for more information.  (disclaimer: I wrote the installation recipe for el-get so obviously I am biased to my solution)

The difference from the solution using pip is that it setups the Emacs side of Pymacs correctly.

Comment: A few lines detailing how to get some basic use of ropemacs and what to add to your .emacs would be really useful here. Despite having run the el-get-install ropemacs without errors, I am still missing the steps necessary to get this package working...

Comment: In spite of it's title, this question only enquired about installing pymacs.  Meanwhile you can tell if pymacs is working by doing M-x pymacs-eval, and then entering a simple python expression.  For example: [i*2 for i in range(1..10)] should return (2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18).

Answer (score 7):

[Installation section](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html#installation) of Pymacs manual is fairly straightforward — don't be afraid to refer to it if unsure. Below are the steps to install Pymacs in Emacs 24. First, in shell, run:

```
sudo pip install rope ropemacs
```

After that in Emacs install Elisp side of Pymacs by adding [Marmalade repository](http://marmalade-repo.org/) and then running `package-install pymacs`. As of February 2014 you can't install Pymacs via `pip`, therefore:

```
git clone http://github.com/pinard/pymacs
cd pymacs
make check
sudo make install
```

`make check` ensures the prerequisites. `sudo make install` puts Pymacs module in Python local modules path, usually `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. People generally frown upon `make install`, because if you lose the Makefile, it can become hard to cleanly uninstall. But you shouldn't fear it, as `pip` uses the same directory, so `pip uninstall pymacs` will work.

In [`~/.emacs.d/init.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile) put:

```
;; Pymacs
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-autoload "pymacs")
```

Evaluate this with `eval-region` and try running Python expressions with `pymacs-eval`. You're good to go.

Comment: So I have to compile pymacs for each virtualenv? I think pymacs installation procedure needs a bit of modernization.

Comment: Windows users here.. the `Makefile` is kinda scary here.

Comment: Except that http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html does not answer and http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/ only echoes its URL. Is there no second source on that installation instructions? It's not in the repo...

Comment: But +1 for the repetition of them here. Succeeded!

Comment: Thanks for the installation procedure. It it awkward, but it may be easier with an `el-get` recipe which does everything (did someone test it ? I couldn't ?) http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Python#With_el-get

Comment: d9k's answer points out that the full documentation is available in the Internet archive.

Answer (score 2):

clone pymacs github, go to folder and proceed tutorial from author. http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html is now offline, if still so see tutorial at https://web.archive.org/web/20130627154513/http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html . Look at chapter "2.4) Install the Pymacs proper" and "2.5 Prepare your .emacs file". Chapters are small, have testing and recomendations for windows user.

Comment: Readers may overlook that the key point in this answer is that the documentation is available in the Internet Archive