# Installing ropemacs using el-get-install

Tags: python, emacs, rope, pymacs

I am trying to set up Emacs for debugging Python scripts, as described [in this blog](http://sunnyeves.blogspot.no/2011/04/debugging-python-on-emacs-ide.html).

I am using Emacs version 24.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

When running `el-get-install ropemacs` from Emacs as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255940/clear-steps-to-install-pymacs-with-emacs-24), I get error:

```
abort: HTTP Error 503: Repository Unavailable
```

The Emacs debugger says:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "el-get: *hg clone rope* Could not install package rope.")
  signal(error ("el-get: *hg clone rope* Could not install package rope."))
  error("el-get: %s %s" "*hg clone rope*" "Could not install package rope.")
  byte-code("\306!\307\310\"\307\311\"\307\312\"\307\313\"\307\314\"\307\315\"\307\316\"\307\317\"\211\320=\204M�\321!\203C�\322\323 \"\210\324\325
#\210\202S�\326\327\"\210\203]�\330!\210\n\203i�\331\f\n#\202r�\332!\205r�\f!.  \207" [proc el-get-sources next final-f package errorm process-exit-status process-get :command-name :buffer-name :message :error :el-get-package :el-get-final-func :el-get-start-process-list :el-get-sources 0 process-buffer set-window-buffer selected-window error "el-get: %s %s" message "el-get: %s" kill-buffer el-get-start-process-list functionp cbuf cname status] 12)
  el-get-start-process-list-sentinel(#<process *hg clone rope*> "exited abnormally with code 255\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for an extern installer here: Ubuntu ships ropemacs already. Just open the Software-Center, put in the string for search and install.

Comment: Thanks, I am in Kubuntu now, so I do not have the Software-Center, should I do `sudo apt-get install python-ropemacs` instead?

Comment: Yes. How about reading/editing this doc ? http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Python#Refactoring