# Emacs's Pymacs error "Symbol's value as variable is void: @DEFADVICE_OK@"

Tags: emacs, pymacs

I have an error "Symbol's value as variable is void: @DEFADVICE_OK@" when I run "M-x pymacs-eval" in emacs (after installing rope, ropemacs, pymacs by this recommendations https://stackoverflow.com/a/22496541/4549375). What is wrong, what can I do for solving this problem?

**If I changed Make file** this way:
`Makefile:
PPPP = $(PYTHON) pppp -C ppppconfig.py => DEFADVICE_OK = 't'
...
prepare:
    $(PPPP) pymacs.el.in => pymacs.el`


 then I do make and check for trying to install **I get this:**
`python pppp -C ppppconfig.py => DEFADVICE_OK = 't' pymacs.el.in => pymacs.el
* = does not end with .in, ignored.
* = does not end with .in, ignored.
* t does not end with .in, ignored.
ERROR: pymacs.el has been modified, keeping it!`

Comment: Could you show the string before `(defadvice documentation...` in the file `pymacs.el`?

Comment: (when @DEFADVICE_OK@

Answer (score 0):

It's strange. The approximate order of execution associated with a variable @DEFADVICE_OK@:

```
Makefile

PPPP = $(PYTHON) pppp -C ppppconfig.py => DEFADVICE_OK = 't'
...
prepare:
    $(PPPP) pymacs.el.in => pymacs.el
```

So, `pymacs.el` doesn't contain @DEFADVICE_OK@ at all (`'t'` instead of this).

Comment: I have changed 257 line in pymacs.el (@DEFADVICE_OK@ => t) after I run "M-x pymacs-eval" I have request "Python expression:" what could I inter in it?

Comment: You shouldn't change the file `pymacs.el` manually because it is generated automatically. You should use `make` command for it. ... `pymacs-eval` evaluates any python expression, e.g. `(lambda(x): 2*x)(3)`